# how to remove outline of html button

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have button on my html page, when i click on that button it show me outer line to button shown as below image.

[image]

here when i click on reset button it show me outer as above image.

**Html code:**

```
< input type="reset" value="" class="resetButton" />
```

**css code:**

```
.resetButton
{
    margin: 0px;
    background:url(../images/button/Reset2.png) no-repeat;
    border: none; 
    width: 90px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thought so check out my answer should make it clear :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this:

```
input[type="reset"]:focus{
    outline: none;   
}
```

or just

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;   
}
```

if you don't want that outline to all the input types.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `display: block;`

```
.resetButton
{
    margin: 0px;
    background:url(../images/button/Reset2.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    border: none; 
    width: 90px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normally a chrome issue, the main thing to note here is that it is an outline not a border.

Try

```
.resetButton{ outline: none; }
```

For more info check out http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#dynamic-outlines

Also check out this post on the dangers of removing the border completely 
[Google Chrome > Textboxes > Yellow border when active..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875195/google-chrome-textboxes-yellow-border-when-active)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) CSS property.

To style a button that is being clicked, you can use [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aactive) pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `outline: none` to your css:

```
.resetButton
{
    margin: 0px;
    background:url(../images/button/Reset2.png) no-repeat;
    border: none; 
    width: 90px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.resetButton, .resetButton:visited
{
    margin: 0px;
    background:url(../images/button/Reset2.png) no-repeat;
    display: block;

    width: 90px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
.resetButton:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also be `box-shadow`. Try something like:

```
.resetButton{ box-shadow: none; }
```

or

```
resetButton:focus{ box-shadow: none; }
```