# CSS focused button keeps border

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
.some-button: focus {
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
}
```

But still when I click on it, it does turn red, but there is still a visible border. Is there something I'm missing that's applying the border?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447232/how-to-remove-outline-of-html-button does this help?

Comment: You need to define *outline: none;* on focus.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remove the space before `focus` and add `outline: none`.

```css
.some-button:focus {
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="some-button">Some Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, this is what do you want:

```
.some-button:focus {
    background-color: red;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
  }
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I thought setting border to none would do the trick. What's the difference between that and outline?

Comment: You are welcome. You can read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) for learn outline. Buttons default focus css is `outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px;`. You can add button and inspect it for the see this. My English skills are not good. Sorry if i make mistake in my sentences

Answer (score 1):

When focusing an element, `outline` style is set globally so you need to update the value of `outline` too.
And also remove the space before `focus`.

```
.some-button:focus {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```