# Why is outline:none not considered good practice?

Tags: html, accessibility, css, outline

**Thanks all. This was a really good discussion and clarifies a lot for me.**

I'm working on an input field and want to remove the outline but people say it's a bad practice. I don't understand why. After all, different browsers have different outlines, and that gets rid of uniformity.

**Without outline:**

```
form input[type="text"],
form input[type="email"],
form input[type="password"],
form textarea {
  color: #000 !important;
  border: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 7px 13px; 
}
  form input[type="text"]:focus,
  form input[type="email"]:focus,
  form input[type="password"]:focus,
  form textarea:focus {
  outline: none; }
```

My thinking is that to increase uniformity, it is better to get rid of the outline, but I suppose some would argue for accessibility. I could still just add a border or box shadow for accessibility, AND this would help the site look uniform across all browsers:

```
form input[type="text"],
form input[type="email"],
form input[type="password"],
form textarea {
  color: #000 !important;
  border: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 7px 13px; 
}
  form input[type="text"]:focus,
  form input[type="email"]:focus,
  form input[type="password"]:focus,
  form textarea:focus {
  /* IMPORTANT */ box-shadow: 0px 0px 2pt 2pt #008bd1;
  outline: none; }
```

So I still don't understand the argument that outline: none is bad practice.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/bCGZQ/

**Edit:** Both answers are good, but because of the debate sparked by the first one, I will accept it.

Comment: Why can't you just use a custom outline? Why do you have to remove the browser-given outline and put a box shadow in its place?

Comment: A big reason - the outline is independent of the layout, allowing elements like links to be highlighted (remember, it's not just form elements you are concerned with). A border will change the layout. Box shadows aren't fully supported and may be hard for some users to see. Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875195/google-chrome-textboxes-yellow-border-when-active/3875216#3875216

Comment: you might check out the reasoning (though they don't say explicitly that it is "bad") in #2 here: http://sixrevisions.com/css/10-random-css-tricks-you-might-want-to-know-about/

Comment: @NappingRabbit `border` doesn't allow for `border-radius` (see fiddle for example). Also see http://www.outlinenone.com @BoltClock the box shadow looks pretty good (see Bootstrap). Also, can you explain what you mean by custom outline? @Tim the border doesn't always change layout.

Comment: I'm not talking about aesthetics here, but I missed that you have a border radius which `outline` does indeed not account for. As for outlines, read up about the `outline` property. There's more to it than just `outline: none`.

Comment: @Tim Medora: Text and box shadows don't affect layout either, although there's that issue with browser support...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Outline is largely an accessibility feature and should be available on tabbable elements to indicate focus during keyboard navigation.

> It provides visual feedback for links that have "focus" when navigating a web document using the TAB key (or equivalent). This is especially useful for folks who can't use a mouse or have a visual impairment. If you remove the outline you are making your site inaccessible for these people.

http://www.outlinenone.com

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't just get rid of the outline. I put box-shadow in its place. Is it still bad practice?

Comment: No, as long as you're providing some sort of feedback or indicator when an element is focused, it's fine. It's the practice of removing `outline: none` *alone* that is frowned upon.

Comment: It depends on the specifics of your box shadow. Imagine that you're an elderly user with mild cataracts, for example. Are subtle box shadows going to be of any value?

Comment: Another argument against box shadows is that not all browsers support them. So an older browser that uses `outline` but doesn't support box shadows is going to not be so great for the visually-impaired user. Supporting those browsers is a personal preference I suppose. If you're going to go so far as worrying about accessibility (I do), you probably want to support as many browsers as possible.

Comment: I agree with @SombreErmine. The box shadow support is definitely an issue, but I suppose border could be used as a fallback.

Answer (score 6):

Setting `outline:none;` is not bad.

Having no `:focus` style is bad.

If you remove the (typically by default provided) `outline`, make sure to set an alternative style (e.g. `border`) when focusing interactive elements. Of course the alternative has to be accessible, which may or may not be the case for `box-shadow` (check the contrast, have color blindness in mind, check if it’s supported for your visitors, etc.).

Simple way to test: Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key on your page. You should always be able *to see* what you are focusing currently. If this specific style has high enough contrast, doesn’t rely on color alone, and is supported by your visitor’s browsers, you are fine.

Comment: Folks that use `box-shadow` should also make sure it works in Windows high-contrast mode by setting a fallback `outline: transparent solid 2px;` https://blog.umairhafeez.com/better-yet-accessible-focus