# Google chrome yellow outilne can't be removed

Tags: css, google-chrome, outline

i used the css property to remove the yellow outline from google chrome but still no result back it is always there and i tried all the options i found outher such as:

```
input[type="text"]:focus {outline:none;}

input:focus {outline:none;}

input[type="text"]:focus {outline-style:none;box-shadow:none;border-color:transparent;}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175951/how-do-i-stop-chrome-from-yellowing-my-sites-input-boxes,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875195/google-chrome-textboxes-yellow-border-when-active

Answer (score 2):

try to add (!important)

```
   input[type="text"] .btn:focus {
   outline-color: transparent !important;
   }

   input:focus {outline:none !important;}

   input[type="text"]:focus {outline-style:none;box-shadow:none;border-color:transparent !important;}
```

Comment: thank you for the help and the problem was on google chrome it self i did reset google chrome settings and it all went good. thanks again.